# changing title of windows start command

Tags: batch-file, wget

When I am using following command every thing goes well

```
start "myping" ping google.com -n 20
```

It runs in a window with title myping

But when I run following command It doesn't use my given title

```
start "mywget" %PATHTOWGET%wget.exe ..options....
```

The wget command executes well it downloads file But the title of window changes
I need it to check whether my process completed or not. I am using following command to test it

```
tasklist /V /FI "WindowTitle eq mywget"
```

After finishing the download I am running remaining part of batch script 
There might be other process using same program so I can't use to test all wgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one solution... don't know whether correct option or not, but its not changing the title at the end I gave **-q --show-progress** so that it doesn't change the title and also shows progress

```
start "mywget" %PATHTOWGET%wget.exe ..options.... -q --show-progress
```

let me know if any other answer one has